# Encountering some problems with walking through a folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I've encountered a small issue with trying to calculate the amount of memory I had by walking through a specific folder using os.walk(). It seems that it would work walking through the specified folder (Basically first round) and identifying whether the object is a file or a folder.

The issue arises when it walking through the second round (first sub folder of first round). It will not capture some files and would return an error.

```
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(original_root_folder):
        space()
        print('The current folder is ' + folderName)

        for subfolder in subfolders:
            print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder + ', Size is ', (os.path.getsize(subfolder) / 1000), " KB")
            total_size_of_folder = total_size_of_folder + os.path.getsize(subfolder)

        for filename in filenames:
            print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename + ', Size is ', (os.path.getsize(filename) / 1000), " KB")
            total_size_of_folder = total_size_of_folder + os.path.getsize(filename)

    print("Total of folder",(total_size_of_folder/1000)," KB")
```

**This is the result of the first round which is the desired result**

```
    The current folder is C:\Users\Someone\Desktop
    SUBFOLDER OF C:\Users\Someone\Desktop: COMP, Size is  4.096  KB
    SUBFOLDER OF C:\Users\Someone\Desktop: compa, Size is  0.0  KB
    SUBFOLDER OF C:\Users\Someone\Desktop: compa2, Size is  4.096  KB
    SUBFOLDER OF C:\Users\Someone\Desktop: HitFilm Express 2017 Exports, Size is  0.0  KB
```

**This is the second round**

```
    The current folder is C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\COMP
    SUBFOLDER OF C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\COMP: comp2402a1, Size is  0.0  KB
    FILE INSIDE C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\COMP: comp2402a1.zip, Size is  5.786  KB
```

**This is the error**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Someone/Desktop/Python testing/reg.py", line 129, in <module>
        print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename + ', Size is ', (os.path.getsize(filename) / 1000), " KB")
      File "C:\Users\Someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
        return os.stat(filename).st_size
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'input.txt'
```

I was expecting the inclusion of the file "input.txt" however it apparently cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.path.getsize() operates in current working directory.

Replace `os.path.getsize(filename)`

with `os.path.getsize(os.path.join(folderName, filename))`